# Bind function from string

Tags: javascript

I  have a custom ASP.Net control that has a function name to be attached inside a javascript object:

```
<custom:myControl runat="server" id="something" OnClientOpened="myFunc" />
```

I then have a state javascript object that has the string "myFunc":

```
state.onClientOpened // contains "myFunc"
```

I am binding a function to the slideUp argument like this:

```
// this code is inside an Object
// Simplified for clarity

$el.slideUp(200, window[state.onClientOpened]);
```

I have no control over what goes into the OnClientOpened property so then I tested something that wasnt in the global namespace:

```
var MyObject = function() {

    var myFunc = function() {
        doSomething();
    };

    return {
        myFunc: myFunc
    };
}();
```

The `state.onClientOpened` would now contain:

```
onClientOpened = "MyObject.myFunc";
```

This obviously breaks it. Whats the best approach for this? I'm thinking some sort of eval but I'm hoping for another approach if possible.

Eval solution:

```
$el.slideUp(200, eval("window." + state.onClientOpened));
```

Comment: Did my last update answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the options I can see so far.

Approach 1 (eval):

```
$el.slideUp(200, eval("window." + state.onClientOpened));
```

Approach 2 (Parse it):

```
var onclientOpened;
var splitArray = state.onclientOpened.split(".");

for (var i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        onclientOpened = window[splitArray[i]];
    } else {
        onclientOpened = onclientOpened[splitArray[i]];
    }
}

$el.slideUp(200, onclientOpened);
```

Approach 2 seems to be the "safest" one, but would appreciate other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap all your code in an anonymous function, not part of it, then you don't have to worry about global namespace pollution. And you don't need to reference the whole `window` rigamarole, just refer to the function as the callback itself.

```
(function () {

  var myFunc = function() {
    doSomething();
  };

  // Simplified for clarity
  $el.slideUp(200, myFunc);

})();
```

#### Approach 2

```
var MyObject = {

  myFunc: function() {
    doSomething();
  }

};

onClientOpened = MyObject.myFunc;
```

#### Approach 3

```
// approach 2, but with this change:
onClientOpened = MyObject["myFunc"];

// or if MyObject also comes from the server,
onClientOpened = window["MyObject"]["myFunc"]
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to keep the approach I'm showing, I've commented a lot of code that would explain why.

Comment: Okay I added a second approach you can try.

Comment: That would work but the string comes from the server, which is why I can't use that.

Comment: Then using approach2:
onClientOpened = MyObject[someVariableWithFuncName];

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, @itsmejodie

Comment: I will update the question again to show why I need this and why I need it to be a string: <custom:myControl runat="server" id="something" OnClientOpened="MyObject.myFunc" />

Comment: Do you see that I made it a string? `MyObject.myFunc === MyObject["myFunc"]`

Comment: The MyObject is not a string, that's the same approach as the Window["myFunc"] / window[onClientOpened]

Comment: Ah, you mean myObject needs to come from the server as well? I updated above.

Answer (score 0):

The variable attached to the `window` namespace is just `MyObject`, not `myFunc`.  If you want to access the function, try doing it like so:

```
window["MyObject"]["myFunc"];
```

You can split the string coming in from the server by using `split`.

```
var params = onClientOpened.split(".");

 $el.slideUp(200,window[params[0]][params[1]]);
```

Comment: Actually, I am self instantiating the MyFunc object so it does work like so.

Comment: I see, new solution.  Tested in Chrome JS console.